# Where to place voting buttons on posts?

Tags: controls, voting

I am making a little question site like Yahoo Answers and I am going to have a voting system on it. But I am stuck on where I should place the up/down vote buttons. I have it in the right corner right now:

[image]

But, I don't know if that is a convenient place for users and there will be a problem when the answer is longer, it won't look right if it goes under the buttons (since I am positioning them inside the answer div) and it probably also would not look right if the text wraps around the buttons. **What is an appropriate location for these voting options?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple patterns of users on voting sites. Some users exclusively read content. Some users read and occasionally vote. And some users vote obsessively, rating every piece of content.

**Users who vote are the most valuable** users on a rated content site; you want to encourage voting, and assist those who do vote in being able to do so easily. Because of this, almost all sites with user-voted content put it **on the left for easy scanning** so that you can quickly see what items you have voted on, and so that the option to vote is the first thing users see.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but then where would the profile picture go?

Comment: Which is more important to your users... the face of the poster, or the rating of the post? I will guarantee that it's the rating, so it should get prime position (left edge), and the profile picture should be sent to a less primary spot such as the right edge.

Comment: Yeah that's true. By _right edge_ do you mean the top or bottom edge?

Comment: Other than giving prime spot to the voting score and arrows, I am making no recommendation about the location of the profile picture; 'right edge' is just an off-the-cuff position I've seen other sites use. I think that is something that can be chosen based on aesthetic rather than UX, since it is of lower importance. SE puts it on the lower right; many comment sites put it on the upper right. I just don't think it should compete with the voting and score (which are of prime importance), so I believe it should be on the right, not the left.

Comment: Reddit usually skips a picture completely, and puts the username just to the right of the voting buttons. Some subreddits (example: [/r/dota2](http://reddit.com/r/dota2/) include custom profile images to the right of the voting buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Next to a large icon synonymous with ranking and a number/count.

A heart, a thumbs up, stars, an up arrow etc.

Comment: And *where* would you place this icon? (and on another point, *why* is an icon necessary?)

Comment: I'm saying include an icon near or next to your button.  An icon is not necessary but it draws my eye to the feature as it is a visual pattern that I recognize immediately.